# angular - can I load a folder instead of each file separately?

Tags: css

this is how I load some libs to my angular project:

```
   <!DOCTYPE html>
   <head>
   <meta charset="ISO-8859-1">
   <script src="lib/angular.js"></script>
   <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.min.css">
   <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/effects.css">
   </head>
   <body>
   </body>
   </html>
```

now, suppose I wanted to load another css file that is also stored in the "css" folder. Could I declare just the folder and have all ".css" files inside properly loaded to the project? For example:

```
   <!DOCTYPE html>
   <head>
   <meta charset="ISO-8859-1">
   <script src="lib/angular.js"></script>
   <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.min.css">
   <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/*.css">            <--- here!
   </head>
   <body>
   </body>
   </html>
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, **no**. Angular is a **front-end** framework, and you **cannot** load all the CSS files in a folder with only front-end languages without specifying them individually.

If you have access to a back-end language, you can **scan** the directory and work out what files are contained within. Then you can use a loop to individually write each link to your HTML.

Without a back-end language, the best thing you can do is package up all of the CSS or JS files used in a project into a single file. This improves performance, and also allows you to easily compress the code.